# Building an aggregator using R Shiny. Alternatives?

Tags: r, shiny, web-applications

I am trying to host an aggregator which I've constructed in R on a web app. I've been using Shiny but it has little to no UI/UX customization options. Any alternatives? I don't want to redo the whole script in python and build it on Flask, but is there any way I can host my R program on a platform which gives me more front end flexibility?

I can go for Flask and Python generally but its exhaustive.

Comment: "Shiny ... has little to no UI/UX customization options": in my experience, that simply isn't true.  (See, for example, [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/gallery/).)  The Shiny UI is built on Bootstrap.  How much more customisation do you want?  Please be more specific about the limitations you are encountering.